# Main DC cable for combiner box to central inverter

Tags: dc

What is the best to be used (annealed or standard or flexible class 5) for 1 x 150 mm<sup>2</sup> cable to transmission the DC power from combiner box to central inverters?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your local  rules equivalent to UL1741 and tradeoffs for cost, availability and labour.

[Some](http://ttps://www.solarpowerworldonline.com/2015/06/what-is-a-combiner-box/) use flexible whip cables.[image]